# На Главной странице не работает правильно вывод (неккоректно работает цикл)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Я создал тему с нуля. И мне нужно было чтоб на главной странице(Главная)

http://www.wnero.esy.es/home/

и при заходе на сайт по адресу

```
http://www.wnero.esy.es
```

выводились записи,страницы должны быть одинаковы ибо и главная и index.php это для меня одно и тоже.

Для этого я создал шаблон index.php в нем прописал название шаблона,для того чтоб указать для страницы Главная
(это страница -- http://www.wnero.esy.es/home/ )
в консоли администратора используемым шаблоном.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: index.php
 *
 * Шаблон index.php.
 *
 */

?>
```

Далее прописал цикл вордпресс для вывода записи

```
     <?php if( have_posts())
     { while( have_posts() ){ the_post(); ?>



 <div class="fotonews"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-img-link wpc-back-bg" style="background-image:url{'<?php get_the_post_thumbnail_url()?>'}"><?php  the_post_thumbnail() ?></a></div>

  <div id="one_newsright" <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>

 <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <button class="news_btn">Читать полностью</button></a>

                                </div>



                                               <?php } /* конец while */ ?>


                                                <?php
                                                } // конец if
                                                else 
                                                    echo "<h2>Записей нет.</h2>";
                                                ?>
```

В итоге вывод записей на странице начальной работает нормально

```
http://www.wnero.esy.es
```

А на Главной странице почему то не работает ---вместо записей выдает не запись а страницу в цикле

```
http://www.wnero.esy.es/home/
```

Вопрос--почему на Главной странице не работает правильно вывод ---вместо записей выдает не запись 
а страницу в цикле?

Еще прилагаю скрин БД,где опции прописаны(wp_options) может там что то не так

Кроме ссылок, прилагаю тему с БД

логин admin пароль adminadmin

а ссилки не могу приложить так как не хватает балов репутации нужно не меньше 10
поэтому выделил как код

```
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwawlIkqc59tbkZzRHNFSEVuNUk
```

Еще прилагаю скрин БД,где опции прописаны(wp_options) может там что то не так

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwawlIkqc59tMjB2T3lnalNOdFU
```

Comment: оффтоп:
у вас там где Лизинговая компания крид в первой строке стрелка криво заезжает

Comment: @Oleksandr 
Спасибо..да действительно

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Решение мне уже дали на другом форуме.

<?php $query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) 
);
if( $query->have_posts())
     { while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post(); ?>



Вопрос собственно закрыт.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт.

решение

```
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) 
);
if( $query->have_posts())
     { while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post(); ?>
```